# pthread_t to gdb thread id

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

Does anyone know a way to go from a pthread_t to what GDB displays with info threads?

So I have:

```
(gdb) info threads
  37 Thread 22887  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  36 Thread 22926  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  35 Thread 22925  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  34 Thread 22924  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  33 Thread 22922  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  32 Thread 22921  0xb7704422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()

(gdb) p m_messageQueue->m_creationThread
$3 = 2694822768
(gdb) p/x m_messageQueue->m_creationThread
$4 = 0xa09fbb70
```

Does anyone know how I figure out which thread this is?  It would appear to be 22768, but none of my threads go that low.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing.. but my problem is worse - I have a need to recover pthread_id first from context (it's an embedded library running in other process thread.. ew)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of pthread_t is not the same as that thread's system dependent thread id (in Linux `gettid(2)`) which you see in GDB.

AFAIK, there isn't any function to convert between the two. You need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: This is correct.  See answer at  *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558469/how-do-i-get-a-thread-id-from-an-arbitrary-pthread-t/558815#558815* for additional info.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll grab it where I care about which thread things occur on.

Comment: Actually it seems this is deprecated and I have to use syscall(SYS_gettid); instead.

Answer (score 29):

New versions of `GDB` actually output the value of `pthread_t` in the `info thread`, making association of `pthread_t` with thread number trivial.

For example, using `GDB 7.0`:

```
cat t.c
#include <pthread.h>

void *fn(void *p)
{
  sleep(180);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t pth1, pth2;
  pthread_create(&pth1, 0, fn, 0);
  pthread_create(&pth2, 0, fn, 0);
  pthread_join(pth1, 0);
  return 0;
}

gcc -g -m32 -pthread t.c && gdb -q ../a.out

(gdb) r
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xf7e56b90 (LWP 25343)]
[New Thread 0xf7655b90 (LWP 25344)]

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0xffffe405 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) info thread
  3 Thread 0xf7655b90 (LWP 25344)  0xffffe405 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  2 Thread 0xf7e56b90 (LWP 25343)  0xffffe405 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 1 Thread 0xf7e576b0 (LWP 25338)  0xffffe405 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) up 2
#2  0x080484e2 in main () at t.c:13
13    pthread_join(pth1, 0);
(gdb) p/x pth1
$1 = 0xf7e56b90  ## this is thread #2 above
(gdb) p/x pth2
$2 = 0xf7655b90  ## this is thread #3 above
```

Comment: gdb 6.8-27 prints:
`* 1 process 22749  0x000000385c8cd372 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6`
gdb 7.0.1 prints:
`* 1 Thread 22749  0x000000385c8cd372 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6`
gdb 7.2-55.1 prints:
`* 1 Thread 0x40c68940 (LWP 22749)  0x000000385c8cd372 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6`

So the `GDB 7.0` statement is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: If you have a lot of threads, you can then use `thread find 0xf7655b90` to give you something like: Thread 3 has target id 'Thread 0xf7655b90 (LWP 25344)'