# Recover pthread context (thread id) in Linux

Tags: linux, pthreads

Is there any universal solution to recover a `pthread_t` value for current thread context?

The code is required for a loadable .so for multithreaded app, so I want to somehow receive library's thread id to understand this thing better - using gdb (details at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188089/pthread-t-to-gdb-thread-id) question).

The app may utilize Boost, GLib, thousand of other pthreads wrappers - I don't care, just need the actual thread ID without modifying app's source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just call `pthread_self()` to get the `pthread_t` for the current thread.