# Set thread's "nice level" from creator thread?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, scheduling

I am working on thread priorities within my application. There is one realtime thread scheduled with `SCHED_RR`. I use `pthread_setschedparam` to set this policy and the priority for it. `pthread_setschedparam` takes the thread id as a first argument, so after creating a thread with `boost::thread` I can set its realtime priority.

However, another thread should have a certain nice-level, but no realtime scheduling. I can use

```
pid_t tid;
tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
int ret = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid, nicelevel);
```

to set its nice level to `ǹicelevel`, but this is working only if I modify the thread function to contain the lines above. Is there a way to set the nice level from the method that creates the thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread) class exposes a public `native_handle()` method. In a pthreads-based implementation, this method *might* return a `tid` (it also *might* return a `pthread_t *`, depending on the meaning of `handle` in this particular case).

If it indeed returns a `tid`, using it should solve your problem. Otherwise, you'll probably have to relay the value returned by `gettid()` from the thread function to the global scope, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558469/how-do-i-get-a-thread-id-from-an-arbitrary-pthread-t/558815#558815) suggests.