# How to get the thread ID for a C++ program?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Right now I'm doing this:

```
std::cout << pthread_self() << std::end;
```

But it seems like that returns a hexadecimal number. How can I get the actual thread ID in decimal form using some function in the pthread_t.h library?

Comment: You can't get that information from the pthreads API because the pthreads API is designed to be portable -- in particular, it's designed to work even on systems that don't have integer thread IDs.  That's why pthread_self() returns an implementation-defined/opaque type (pthread_t) rather than a more concrete type, and why you can't even e.g. compare pthread_t values using the == operator (you have to call pthread_equals() instead).  The short answer is:  you'll need to use an OS-specific API (like gettid()) to get the information you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a thread ID from an arbitrary pthread\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558469/how-do-i-get-a-thread-id-from-an-arbitrary-pthread-t)

Comment: Why do you care?  If you need to uniquely identify a thread, just assign them your own ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you want threads to have an ID that meets certain requirements, assign them one. They won't "just happen to have one" without you doing something to make it happen.