# Two threads entering in infinite loops

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, operating-system

I am learning the concept of pthread. I wrote a code for the following question :

> Implement the following model: Create a master thread. It opens a
>   file. At random intervals, the master thread creates worker threads at
>   random intervals and each worker thread will sleep for random
>   intervals before it reads a line from the file and finally exits.

I wrote the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

char c;

void *f1(void *f)
{
    printf("Calling from thread 1\n");
    sleep(rand()%2);
    while(c!='\n'&& c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("1 %c\n",c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *f2(void *f)
{
    printf("Calling from thread 2\n");
    sleep(rand()%2);
    while(c!='\n' && c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("2 %c\n",c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid1,tid2;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("new.txt","r");
    int i;
    c=getc(f);
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        i=rand()%2;
        sleep(i);
        pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,f1,(void *)f);
        i=rand()%2;
        sleep(i);
        pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,f2,(void *)f);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

While executing, the code enters an infinite loop. Sometimes only the first line is being executed then it enters an infinite loop. Even when I used `pthread_join`, the problem was not solved.
Why is it entering an infinite loop?

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;`. `EOF` does not fit in a `char`, so `c != EOF` will never be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st thread function f1, you are writing

```
while(c!='\n'&& c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("1 %c\n",c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
```

Then you get back to the main function and to the second thread. So right now, the value of c is `'\n'`. Thus in f2, you will not enter the loop. Hence, the while loop in main will continue forever since the value of c is not changing and is stuck in `'\n'`. This is reason for getting the infinite loop. So, you can also conclude that the threads that you created are not entering in any infinite loop.

Solution :

As soon as you exit the loop in the thread functions, change the value of c.

```
if(c!=EOF)
   c = getc(f);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some issues:

- Your using one global variable `c` in `main` and both threads.  So they are all overwriting the value used by the others.
- You have an almost exact copy of the code run as thread: `f1()` and `f2()`.  Instead you can have one function `f()` that you run by multiple threads.  This is a main idea of multi-threading.
- You can print the thread ID using [`pthread_self()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709692/1971013).
- `pthread_exit()` is called implicitly when you return from a function.
- `main()` was not started as a thread explicitly, so calling `pthread_exit()` does not make sense.
- You're lacking communication & synchronisation between the threads, telling each other which line they'll be reading.  You should use the 'master' thread to keep track, and let each 'worker' thread ask where to read.  (This is a non-trivial assignment I'd say.)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT AFTER @Maksim Solovjov COMMENT**

Actually the issue is you are reading only a line is read i.e. till `'\n'` is hit. Once any of the thread reads this `'\n'` character, no other thread (or main while-loop) will read further. And thus it'll stuck in loop forever.

So, if you change the while loop in both the thread as below,

```
while(c!=EOF)
```

threads will go ahead and read next line. Finally the flow will reach EOF and thread can exit.

After modifying your threads code will look like

```
void *f1(void *f)
{
    printf("Calling from thread 1\n");
    sleep(rand()%2);
    while( c!=EOF)  //======>>>this is where change is required.
    {
        printf("1 %c\n",c);
        c=getc((FILE *)f);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: This would break the logic: only the worker threads are supposed to read the line from input judging from the assignment statement

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov I updated the answer based on your comment. The issue was largely the same, the `getc()` was not reaching till EOF :)

Comment: But I am supposed to read 1 line from a single thread. By giving the condition (c!=EOF), I am reading the whole file from a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

There are never "two threads in infinite loop". Its the main thread which is in inifinite loop. This is happening because:
You are reading file in two different functions called by different threads till either of one reach EOF or "\n".
Say your thread executing function one reaches "\n" it will quit. But now main thread will go in inifinite loop because EOF will never come as both function checking for while(c!='\n'&& c!=EOF) to further read file.

For coming out of this situation, you can use one global state variable, which will take care of "\n" blocking.

Code will be look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

char c;
int isBlock;

void *f1(void *f)
{
    printf("Calling from thread 1\n");
    sleep(rand()%2);
    while((c!='\n' || isBlock) && c!=EOF)
    {
        isBlock = 0;
        printf("1 %c\n",c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
    isBlock = 1;
    printf("exiting from thread 1\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *f2(void *f)
{
    printf("Calling from thread 2\n");
    sleep(rand()%2);
    while((c!='\n'|| isBlock) && c!=EOF)
    {
        isBlock = 0;
        printf("2 %c\n",c);
        c=getc(f);
    }
    isBlock = 1;
    printf("exiting from thread 2\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid1,tid2;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("checkConnection.cpp","r");
    int i;
    c=getc(f);
    isBlock = 0;
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        //c=getc(f);
        i=rand()%2;
        sleep(i);
        pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,f1,(void *)f);
        i=rand()%2;
        sleep(i);
        pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,f2,(void *)f);
}
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```