# Using pthread_t as a key in map

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I would like to store a class of my own in a map, with the key being of type pthread_t.(Each object of my class contains a pthread_t data member so I want each instance to be associated with that pthread_t as a key, in a map)
The problem is pthread_t can't be compared, only with pthread_equal so I can't put it in a map as a key.

I have seen unordered_map, but how can I implement a hash function for pthread_t?

Until now I thought about comparing them using pthread_self(), but that's also impossible since the returned value is pthread_t, and I don't want to use the fact that this is just a typedef for unsigned long int.

If using some sort of map is not possible, how can I store pthread_t's objects in a container and find them fast using pthread_self() funcion?

Comment: Why not use a vector?

Comment: May be this helps a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558469/how-do-i-get-a-thread-id-from-an-arbitrary-pthread-t

Comment: @KerrekSB, I am using a vector now but that means I have to search for a thread in O(n), my question is if it's possible to search better using map or something like that...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I don't really understand the answers in this post. Some of them use the assumption that pthread_t is an unsigned long int, something I would like to avoid. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I understand from the first answer is that I can give each thread an ID I can choose manually?

Comment: @dor132 _"is that I can give each thread an ID I can choose manually?"_ Not in a portable way unfortunately. The other answers are more useful for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so I can gettid instead or with pthread_self() to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This way it should work :

```
bool myCmp(const pthread_t &a, const pthread_t &b)
{
  return memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(pthread_t)) < 0;
}

map<pthread_t, myDataType, myCmp> myMap;
```