# Is there a way to link a linux's thread TID and a pthread_t "thread ID"

Tags: linux, pthreads, pid

On linux a thread is identified by a `pthread_t` or a TID. I'm looking for bridges between these two kinds of thread ids:

- given a `pthread_t` can I get it's `TID` ? [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558469/how-do-i-get-a-thread-id-from-an-arbitrary-pthread-t/558815#558815) not without hacking in pthread's internals :( but i'm still asking in case someone has a clean way to do it.
- given a `TID` (or `PID`), can I get a `pthread_t` handle to it ?

---

Because the term "thread id" is ambiguous in this context (and in the documentation), a bit of background:

- The POSIX pthread API defines a `pthread_t` type, all functions that query/act on a thread use a `pthread_t` argument, and we can get such a handle e.g. with `pthread_self()`. The documentation calls these "thread ids", but here I call them handles to disambiguate, because multiple different `pthread_t` values may represent the same thread, hence the need for `pthread_equal(pthread_t, pthread_t)`.
- On the other hand, on linux at least, there is a concept of `TID`s or thread ids. One can get the current `TID` with a system call: `syscall(SYS_gettid)`. The `TID` has a few interesting properties such as being unique to a thread, and comparable to `PID`s, which allows to easily identify the main thread, etc.

Comment: What do you intend to do with `TID`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: easier debugging/tracing (since it's unique), doing operations on the main thread from another, or using linux-specific thread functions that aren't abstracted by pthread.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no portable way to do so because [there is no requirement for `pthread_t` to map to `tid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_equal.html):

> Implementations may choose to define a thread ID as a structure. This allows additional flexibility and robustness over using an int. For example, a thread ID could include a sequence number that allows detection of "dangling IDs" (copies of a thread ID that has been detached). Since the C language does not support comparison on structure types, the pthread_equal() function is provided to compare thread IDs.

Historically, prior to [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library), `pthread_t` did not map 1-to-1 to `tid`.

You would need to use pthreads library implementation details to peek at `tid`. I would not recommend doing that because such code would not be portable.

For the sake of curiosity only, with glibc, [`pthread_t` is a `struct pthread *`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_kill.c;hb=HEAD#l30):

```
27 int
28 __pthread_kill (pthread_t threadid, int signo)
29 {
30   struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;
...
40   pid_t tid = atomic_forced_read (pd->tid);
```

And [`pthread` is](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/descr.h;hb=HEAD#l123):

```
122 /* Thread descriptor data structure.  */
123 struct pthread
124 {
...
166   /* Thread ID - which is also a 'is this thread descriptor (and
167      therefore stack) used' flag.  */
168   pid_t tid;
```

Comment: sad, but thanks for the glibc example anyways. What about the other way round, is there a trick to get a `pthread_t` from a pid/tid ?

Comment: `extern struct pthread *__find_thread_by_id (pid_t tid) attribute_hidden`, note the attribute. Also `struct pthread *self = THREAD_SELF;`