# Gdb core dump on Linux: get Linux LWP out of pid_t tid out of pthread_t

Tags: linux, gdb, pthreads

I have a core dump and I want to get a Linux tid of a pthread in it using gdb. I have reached the point using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343318/4781940):

```
(gdb) p &this->m_thread->m_state->m_Thread
$29 = (pthread_t *) 0x7f05f84bde00

(gdb) p &((struct pthread *)(&this->m_thread->m_state->m_Thread))->tid
$28 = (pid_t *) 0x7f05f84be0d0

(gdb) p *&((struct pthread *)(&this->m_thread->m_state->m_Thread))->tid
$30 = 136478480
```

But the value does not look like LWP **2977**, ... LWP **5110** that I can see when doing `info threads`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What does `p this->m_thread->m_state->m_Thread` show? Because I think what you actually need to do is `p ((struct pthread *)this->m_thread->m_state->m_Thread)->tid`.

Comment: OHHHHHH, I don't understand yet but it worked!!!!!!!!! Thank you! Write your answer please! I want to upvote and accept!