# Print tid out of pthread_t in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343318/4781940) that `pthread_t` is `struct pthread*` on Linux. But I get the error:

```
a.c:35:60: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct pthread’
   35 |   printf("%ld: %ld\n", e, ((struct pthread*)(newthread))->tid);
```

While in `gdb` I can do `p ((struct pthread*)(newthread))->tid` and it works well.

How can I do it in code?

Comment: It appears that `struct pthread` is not exposed to your code.  The debugger may have information on it, but your code does not.  I'm not sure what the purpose is here.  If this is just for debugging something in your program, you could recreate the `struct` and cast to your version to get `tid`.  Just be aware that doing so is not portable/robust and technically undefined behavior in C even though it will work.  Again, it depends on the use case.  You can always get thread id manually with `gettid`.

Comment: @Jason, I try to find a way to learn a tid of a thread created by pthread_create().

Comment: @Jason, this is for debugging purposes. I don't care about correctness, etc.

Comment: The answer you are referring to states "`pthread_t` [...] is just the pointer to an *opaque* `struct pthread`". Opaque means you should not know the internal details of the structure. According to [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html), `pthread_t` could be an integral type instead of a pointer to a structure. Please explain in your question what you want to achieve with accessing this non-portable structure field.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I want in an ugly way, but that's enough for my purposes:

```c
printf("%ld: %d\n", e, *((pid_t*)(((char*)newthread+720))));
```

I just explored it in `gdb` this way:

```
(gdb) p ((struct pthread*)handle)->tid
$1 = 3448

(gdb) p &(((struct pthread*)handle)->tid)
$2 = (pid_t *) 0x7fffd69ff910

(gdb) p ((struct pthread*)handle)
$3 = (pthread *) 0x7fffd69ff640

(gdb) p 0x7fffd69ff910 - 0x7fffd69ff640
$4 = 720

(gdb) p *((pid_t*)(((char*)handle)+720))
$5 = 3448
```

Comment: This is even more ugly and difficult to understand than using your own structure definition as proposed in [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635822/jason)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993170/print-tid-out-of-pthread-t-in-c-on-linux#comment135728801_76993170)

Comment: Yeah, this is soooo much better than using [`gettid()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) as suggested in the very first comment to your question.  

Comment: No, @AndrewHenle, gettid() does not suit here. It returns the tid of the _current_ thread. In my example _newthread_ is not the current thread. It is a thread created by _pthread_create()_ by the current thread.